# Why do we say Vehueesu "ach" samaech? Shouldnt it say maoed samaach?

Tags: sukkah, sukkot

Doesnt ach limit it?  I would think just like we say ushmartem maoed" we should say maoed samaech - be very happy - any ideas

Comment: I believe in the gemara it discusses the limitation imposed by the use of "ach," though I can't recall where... I'll try to look it up in the Torah Temimah

Comment: He quotes the Gemara in Sukkah that states that the chiluk of ach is used to include the last day in the mitzvah of simchah but exclude the first. I don't understand it fully, but there you go...

Comment: Please refine your question. The expression is found directly in the Torah at the end of parshat *R'eh*. What do you mean by "we say"? Who is "we"? We're just reciting part of a Torah verse.

Answer (score 1):

In a Pessikta d'R. Kahana it states that the "אך" is to indicate that a person's happiness in this world is not complete. (Can't locate a source online so here's a picture; line 18)

[image: Pessikta d'Rav Kahana]